# What's written on my whisky bottle?

Tags: перевод

Today I got a whisky bottle from my colleagues at work. Someone wrote something in Russian on it but unfortunately I do not speak Russian. Can anyone tell me what is written on the bottle?

A friend said that it begins with "Thank you from" but he could not read more. Google Translate is also helpless.

Here is an image of the sentence:

[image]

Comment: In the current edition, your question seems to get less constructive. It was completely reworded, and my answer is not related to the question now. You could append your editions to the original post instead of rewording.

Comment: Why shouldn't you write it in cyrillics?  If your system doesn't support cyrillics, use translit.ru

Comment: @Dmitry: I reverted the changes. Thank you very much for your translation!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Russian text:

```
Спасибо от команды тестирования
```

Translation:

```
Thank you from the testing team
```

Comment: My question is, what is the first word? The one that looks like "Yap." Is that someone's name?

Comment: I think this is a signature (maybe of the person who wrote on the bottle).